# Have Site-To-Site (IPSEC) connected but cannot ping anything other than router

Tags: vpn, vlan, azure, ipsec, pfsense

Just setup a new Azure subscription, and i'm stumped trying to troubleshoot why I can't ping any local VMWare machines from a Azure VM. After successfully setting up an IPSec Site-To-Site VPN.

**I am doing this as a learning exercise** to setup a home lab, and working on my crappy networking skills :(

I have the following setup:

- Esxi Server with a VM (Portal) on a vlan50 network
- Managed switch with vlan50 tagging
- pfSense router with 192.168.20.1/24 address on vlan50
- A working IPSec tunnel from my lab **192.168.20.0/24** to Azure
  virtual network **192.168.50.0/24**

So for testing I created 1 VM in on-prem lab, and 1 VM in Azure

- On-prem VM [**Portal**] - **192.168.20.2 vlan50**
- Azure VM [**TestVM**] - **192.168.50.100 (no vlan)**

From the Portal Server, I can ping the local gateway 192.168.20.1,

And from the pfSense I can ping the Azure VM:

[Ping from pfSense to AzureVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WkVQ.jpg)

And from the Azure Server, I can ping the 192.168.20.1 interface.

<strike>Ping from Azure to pfSense interface</strike>, not enough reputation :(

**However**, the VMs cannot see each other\ping each other. I cannot understand this. I added rules in both IPSec & the vlan50 to allow all access to each subnet. I have a feeling my issue is either a Firewall rule, or vlan tag?

Here are some interesting things I'm noticing while troubleshooting:

1. I don't see any ICMP traffic on the vlan50 interface when successfully pinging from pfSense to AzureVM
2. When (unsuccessfully) pinging from AzureVM to Portal box, I see unanswered ICMP requests from 192.168.50.100 when listening on pfSense box on the vlan50 interface

I also created a very crude network outline with screenshots of the configuration I have setup: [Crude Network layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz6sF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I found the answer was the fact that my **Portal** machine that's on-premise has multiple NIC, and the default Gateway doesn't know that route. I added a static gateway and was able to successfully ping each machine

Answer (score 0):

could you elaborate on this a bit more? What do you mean by default gateway? Was this a software config you set up on a firewall locally or was it an Azure service? I would expect you to mean that you set up local routing through a switch or firewall to handle the traffic on-premise, but it is not completely clear by your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).